Calculating the volume of a square
package Pyramid;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareVolume {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length = 0;
        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        double volume = 0;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        SquareVolume vol = new SquareVolume();
        
        System.out.println("ENTER LENGTH: ");
        length = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER WIDTH: ");
        width = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER HEIGHT: ");
        height = input.nextDouble();
        
        vol.VolumeCalc(length, width, height);
        System.out.println("VOLUME: " + volume);
        
    }
    public double VolumeCalc (double length, double width, double height){
        double volume = (length * (width * height));
        return volume;
    }
}

While attempting calculating the volume of a square, I wrote the code above, I'm obviously expecting a result besides 0.0. I can't see where I'm going wrong.

You're ignoring the return value of the VolumeCalc() call. It should be volume = vol.VolumeCalc(....

A square doesn't have a volume so the program is accidentally right. It looks like the goal is to calculate the volume of a cuboid though.

Have you tried either assigning the result of your function VolumeCalc to a variable or directly printing the result of the function? Otherwise you are only printing the value of your volume variable.
In summary, try doing

volume = vol.VolumeCalc(length, width, height);

before printing.

Thanx for getting back to me guys, It was such a small thing, but you guys made it very clear. Thanx once again!
